# $\aleph_2$ Suslin Hypothesis

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

Is it still open whether ZFC+GCH is consistent with the statement that there are no $\aleph_2$-Suslin trees?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From http://www.users.muohio.edu/larsonpb/kly_guessing.pdf (pdf 9 of 16):

> Note that the consistency of GCH + "no $\omega_{2}$-Suslin-trees" is
>   still an open question. ...this old question is now more open than
>   ever.

As best as I can tell, the matter has not been settled in the six years since the published paper above.

**Citation:**

König, B., Larson, P., & Yoshinobu, Y. (2007). Guessing clubs in the generalized club filter. *Fundamenta Mathematicae, 195*(2), 177-191.